# Query showing wrong resut

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tabe in MySQL and I want to get most likes by user_id according to created_on (timestamp)
If there is more than one record then oldest post result should be display.Here is my table "post_likes"

```
id      post_id         likes       created_on
1       91              1           1545311881
2       82              1           1545201971
3       84              1           1545160544
4       91              1           1545146273
5       84              1           1545123998
```

I tried with following query but not working for me

```
select post_id, count(likes) 
from post_likes 
group by post_id 
ORDER BY created_on ASC LIMIT 1
```

Showing me oldest but with 1 like, I want to get maximum+oldest post result.

Comment: provider your expected output in table format

Comment: @fa06 : i just want oldest post (post_id) with hightest count of likes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each post, you need to generate `COUNT(likes)` to see how many likes it has in total, and also `MIN(created_on)` to find out the date of the earliest like for that post. Having done that, you can sort by likes and created date:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(likes) AS likes, MIN(created_on) AS created_on
FROM post_likes
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY likes DESC, created_on ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
post_id     likes   created_on
84          2       1545123998
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8acfaa06d6440ceb93fca559fd4b968b)

**Update** To only look at post likes from the last 24 hours, you need to filter the table first with a subquery that only selects posts which were liked in the last 24 hours (`created_on > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 24 * 60 * 60)`:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(likes) AS likes, MIN(created_on) AS created_on
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM post_likes
      WHERE created_on > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 24 * 60 * 60) p
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY likes DESC, created_on ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Note - for your sample data no posts match this criteria. This [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dcd67689cf776d6c23865040a0e3150a) gives you results if you stretch the criteria out to a longer number of days.

Comment: if i want last 24 hour post result then what should i do ?

Comment: @PriyaJaiswal see my edit. That will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT post_id, count(likes), created_on
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM post_likes Order by created_on
) as t1
group by post_id ORDER BY count(1) desc
LIMIT 1
```

Note: If you want the oldest timestamp for post_id:91, you have to order it by timestamp in asc before group by. Otherwise the timestamp will give you uncertain result.

Comment: @ Anson Woody: if i want to get last 24 hour post result then ?